# update SQL command in C#

Tags: c#, sql, updatecommand

I'm having some troubles parsing SQL query, I'm trying to update the database.
I have a database as follows:

```
name: Users
columns:
ID (int)
userName (string)
LastConnected (string)
isConnected (string)
```

I tried this:

```
SqlCeCommand upDateUserAsConnected = new SqlCeCommand("(update Users set isConnected='Connected' where ID=" + userID + " and userName='"+userName+"')", cn);
```

and that's not working...
what did I do wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by _not working_ ? Any error message or exception? And please learn [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for _SQL Injection_ attacks.

Comment: Are you sure the trouble is in the bit of code you posted?

Comment: I"m getting this exption
{"There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 2,Token in error = update ]"}

Comment: Soner Gönül 
It's for a small project i'm working on nothing serious

Comment: Have you tried the same query but without parentheses?

Comment: yeah..
is a cell that is null can be the problem?

Comment: post how you execute that query.

Comment: 'code'
if (userIDMach && userNameMach)
            {
                try
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    upDateUserAsConnected.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cn.Close();
                    return logInCheckSuccess = true;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Testing");
                }
            }
'code'

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need parentheses within the query string.
Second of all, you have merely written the query here, have you tried to execute it as non-query? How exactly are you running this query?